# Create custom background android like this chat shape

Tags: android, nine-patch

[image]

> 

**How to achieve this ** i tried 9 patch there i cant make this and no direct one available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) images.

Here is one of many [examples](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=37414) with a gradient background.
[image: 9-patch with callout and gradient background]

The expander bars above, below, and to the sides of your image control where the image stretching can occur *and* where the text padding lies.
Here is how to keep the callout in an arbitrary location of the image:
[image]

Here is an interactive online tool for drawing the expanders and downloading the result once you find or finish creating your gradient/callout image: http://draw9patch.com

Comment: Theres no tutorial ,just 2 images with low clarity, can u give me a high resolution one

Comment: @Arju this isn't a "do-it-for-me" site.

Comment: @kcoppock i dont told so, then how can a image be programmed ,give me answer

Comment: @david thanks for the help , i need that projection at left end as a chat symbol, thats y i asked again

Comment: How to make a 9-patch image exactly like the example in your question: 1. Get image editing program such as Gimp (_free_) or Adobe Photoshop. 2. Start with your example. 3. Make the black background transparent (Google how). 4. Clone out all the views on top. 5. Use Google 9-patch editing tool (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) to add the 9-patch expansion bars. @kcoppock is correct that we can't do it for you, but the recipe above will get you there one step at a time if you are willing to do the work.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend these styles: http://www.dibbus.com/2011/02/gradient-buttons-for-android/

Just create a `View` and set the `android:background="@drawable/blueButtonStyle"`

Comment: How would we get the tail of the callout from these buttons?

Comment: This answer does not explain hot to get a 9patch. it only helps on shaping views to the normal shapes.