# Custom Shape while chatting in android using xml file

Tags: android, shapes

I am able to draw custom back ground to xml file using [Shape](http://android-dev-tips-and-tricks.blogspot.in/2012/08/xml-drawables-part-i.html)

But how to add arc or curv at specified place.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a simpler solution would be to use a 9 patch image.

Comment: curv? arc? what are you talking about?

Comment: I think you are looking for [Chat- Bubble](http://adilsoomro.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-listview-with-speech-bubble.html).

Comment: @psking Curv or arc means the pointer at right side of above image

Comment: @Kedarnath yes I am looking for chat bubble in xml not in png

Comment: you cannot do that in xml, either use nine patch drawable or extend Drawable class and override draw method

Comment: Thank you all. 9 patch image is considered and solved. Thank you

Comment: You can use from link :

[Create custom background android like this chat shape][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989942/create-custom-background-android-like-this-chat-shape

Comment: @A.A What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: @A.A you can't make it using shape xml.. 9 patch image will be best

Answer (score 4):

In my library [Facebook Like Button](https://github.com/shamanland/facebook-like-button) I implemented [custom Path](https://github.com/shamanland/facebook-like-button/blob/snapshot/lib/src/main/java/com/shamanland/facebook/likebutton/CalloutPath.java) in order to achieve this goal.

There is ability to specify location of marker wherever you want:

[image]
[image]

Code from [source](https://github.com/shamanland/facebook-like-button/blob/snapshot/lib/src/main/java/com/shamanland/facebook/likebutton/CalloutPath.java):

```
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;

public class CalloutPath extends Path {
    public static final int MARKER_NONE = 0x0;
    public static final int MARKER_LEFT = 0x1;
    public static final int MARKER_TOP = 0x2;
    public static final int MARKER_RIGHT = 0x4;
    public static final int MARKER_BOTTOM = 0x8;
    public static final int MARKER_ALL = 0xf;

    private final RectF oval = new RectF();

    /**
    * @param m marker
    * @param w width
    * @param h height
    * @param s stroke thickness
    * @param r corners radius
    */
    public void build(int m, float w, float h, float s, float r) {
        int fl = factor(m, MARKER_LEFT);
        int ft = factor(m, MARKER_TOP);
        int fr = factor(m, MARKER_RIGHT);
        int fb = factor(m, MARKER_BOTTOM);

        float x0 = s + 0f;
        float x1 = s + r * fl;
        float x2 = s + r + r * fl;
        float x3 = w / 2f - r;
        float x4 = w / 2f;
        float x5 = w / 2f + r;
        float x6 = w - 1f - s - r - r * fr;
        float x7 = w - 1f - s - r * fr;
        float x8 = w - 1f - s;
        float y0 = s + 0f;
        float y1 = s + r * ft;
        float y2 = s + r + r * ft;
        float y3 = h / 2f - r;
        float y4 = h / 2f;
        float y5 = h / 2f + r;
        float y6 = h - 1f - s - r - r * fb;
        float y7 = h - 1f - s - r * fb;
        float y8 = h - 1f - s;

        reset();

        moveTo(x1, y2);

        oval.set(x2 - r, y2 - r, x2 + r, y2 + r);
        arcTo(oval, 180f, 90f);

        if (ft != 0) {
            lineTo(x3, y1);
            lineTo(x4, y0);
            lineTo(x5, y1);
        }

        lineTo(x6, y1);

        oval.set(x6 - r, y2 - r, x6 + r, y2 + r);
        arcTo(oval, 270f, 90f);

        if (fr != 0) {
            lineTo(x7, y3);
            lineTo(x8, y4);
            lineTo(x7, y5);
        }

        lineTo(x7, y6);

        oval.set(x6 - r, y6 - r, x6 + r, y6 + r);
        arcTo(oval, 0f, 90f);

        if (fb != 0) {
            lineTo(x5, y7);
            lineTo(x4, y8);
            lineTo(x3, y7);
        }

        lineTo(x2, y7);

        oval.set(x2 - r, y6 - r, x2 + r, y6 + r);
        arcTo(oval, 90f, 90f);

        if (fl != 0) {
            lineTo(x1, y5);
            lineTo(x0, y4);
            lineTo(x1, y3);
        }

        close();
    }

    public static int factor(int marker, int mask) {
        return (marker & mask) != 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have this arc or curv you should create a custom `jpg`.

But you can use with `corners` and have below :

[image: Test]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already did it using .9patch image.

Comment: I just followed this http://adilsoomro.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-listview-with-speech-bubble.html

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to do it programmatically, you should just use a `nine patch` image resource that make a perfect image for you. If you want to know more about `nine patch` and how it works, have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517693/how-does-a-9patch-png-work-in-android-apps) links. 
As you can see this image makes a perfect chat bubble for you. I already decompiled `Whatsapp` , `Viber` and they all using a `nine patched` image to make a chat bubble. As you can see, the Telegram app also using a [nine patched image](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/msg_out.9.png) to achieve this.

My sample chat bubble image: 
 [image]

I also should mention that you don't need any custom path. It is a typical patched image without any customization.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

make 9patch image like this so that if in conversation lots of text then also it can be adjusted itself and also not stretch or compressed from curve .

Hope it will help you

Comment: Can you help in In-App-purchase for amazon ? Are you aware of Amazon develepment using android SDK?

Comment: it working for big text then whats the problem you are facing buddy ?

Comment: I was having problem, but with  Kedarnath comment it is working

Comment: I followed this http://adilsoomro.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-listview-with-speech-bubble.html